# Is there any way to visually enhance org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

For example making different headline levels appear in different font sizes or changing the color scheme.

Comment: The answer is "yes", but that probably wouldn't help you very much: avoid yes/no questions!   Also, please include in your question a description of what you already tried (e.g. have you looked at the Org manual or the Emacs manual?    Which?  Where?)

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of ways to customize `org-mode`. Many of the `color-theme`s for Emacs (e.g., Zenburn, Monokai) include customizations for the colors and sizes. You can also use the [`org-bullets`](https://github.com/sabof/org-bullets) package to add pretty bullets to each level.

Comment: [org-superstar](https://github.com/integral-dw/org-superstar-mode) seems to be a more advanced, more configurable and better maintained package than org-bullet

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the detailed tweaking that you can do following Ryan's suggestions, you can quickly try doing `M-x customize-themes` and check `leuven` -- it is a good light colour theme with different heading sizes and code blocks highlighted. Another good option is https://github.com/jonnay/org-beautify-theme